# Ansible with Python3 on RedHat/CentOS 7 (python3-dnf issues)

Tags: python, ansible, redhat

I'd like to run Ansible tasks with python3 as the interpreter (there are lots of reasons for why to go to python3 ... one of them being that python2 will not be supported anymore by Ansible).

Unfortunately, doing that on RedHat 7 is not possible as I can't install python3-dnf there (it seems this package is available only for RedHat 8).

Does anyone had that issue and founded a solution for it?

Thanks

Comment: First non sponsored result when typing "python3 redhat7" in https://www.qwant.com search engine => https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/

Comment: Nice ... but probably you didn't saw the problem ... not having python3 on rhel7 but having python3-dnf :-)

Comment: Title: `Ansible with Python3 on RedHat/CentOS 7`. First post sentence: `I'd like to run Ansible tasks with python3 as the interpreter`. You are then only pointing  out you cannot install python3-dnf... which you actually don't need to run ansible on python3 on rhel7. I run ansible on python3 (controller and target) on centos7 and rhel7 daily.

Comment: Well ... Using yum is not supported with python3 ... for that we need dnf ...
Using dnf ... without python3-dnf ... it is not possible :-)
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/dnf_module.html

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunally the answer from Adam isnt helpful when you are building roles that should be available for RedHat/Debian/CentOS/... and you use custom libraries that are only available in Python3 (because we have 2021 and Python2 EoL was 2020). So because of the missing Python3 support for `yum` in CentOS7 you run into a dependency hell problem.

All hosts (whatever OS) should use Python3 as `ansible_python_interpreter`.

All tasks should be running with Python3 (either on controller or on the host). There is one single problem (from my point today) - the task `package`. Even when it is OS-independent, it requires Python2 on CentOS7 (on all other OS's there is no problem with Python3).

What I did - only for this module - switch to Python2 when your host is on CentOS7. For example:

```
- name: "Define Python Interpreter"
  set_fact:
    my_interpreter: "{{ ansible_python_interpreter }}"

- name: "Override Python Interpeter for CentOS7"
  set_fact:
    my_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python"
  when:
    - "ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'"
    - "ansible_distribution_major_version | int == 7"

- name: "Install dependencies"
  package:
    name: "...."
  become: true
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "{{ my_interpreter }}"
```

In all other cases stay with your configured host specific Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use python3 on CentOS 7, then instead of using "dnf" module, you can shell command directly, for example:

```
    - name: Uninstall foo and bar (CentOS)
      become: yes
      shell:
        cmd: "if yum list installed {{ item }};
              then
                yum -y remove {{ item }};
              fi"
        warn: false  # Use shell to workaround the problem with python dnf module: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71668
      loop:
        - foo
        - bar
```

My test shows that the only case that ansible works with python3 is that they are on the same machine and when ansible is installed with

```
python3 -m pip install ansible
```

which is a special situation where the ansible you run on the target machine (tested with `yum` module but presume it will work with `dnf` module).

Comment: It's not big, it's not clever but for our Centos7 it was the only way I could get round the issue of needing python2 for yum (dnf had other issues) and python3 for the uri module (could not find lxml).

Answer (score 1):

I'm one if the Ansible maintainers for the yum and dnf modules. Python 2 will continue to be supported for the remote hosts (hosts in the inventory that you are automating tasks on) but not the controller node (where your are actually running the ansible-playbook command). You can safely continue to use Python 2 on the remote RHEL7 hosts so long as you are running Ansible from a control node that's on Python 3, and even that restriction doesn't exist for the current stable release of Ansible (2.9.10 at the time of this writing) but only for future releases. Hope this helps, happy automating!

Comment: That make sense. Thank you

Comment: @adam-miller: What are the requirements for the remote hosts?  We're running both from and to Centos 7 hosts. We have a couple of roles that need to install python packages on the remote (for managing LDAP and MongoDB). Seems the default version of pip with CentOS7 broke some time in the last week.  Worked a week ago, now fails with _'The C API from Python 3.6+ is required, found sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)'_  It is a super old version of pip, but running against an image that we could upgrade last week now fails.  Is this our problem or a bug?